# How to correctly interpret the results of Power Analysis?

Tags: statistical-power

[image]

Attached is the result of Power Analysis comparing the means of two independent samples.

I am having hard time interpreting the "interpretations" as it is quite convoluted.

Does it say the risk of failure to reject the null hypothesis is not significant? So it says the two means are significantly different from each other? Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the means and standard deviations in each group really were as you've entered, and you were to randomly sample 20 observations from group 1 and 9 observations from group 2, you would obtain a significant difference between the groups (a p-value < $\alpha$, where you've set $\alpha$ to 0.05) 98.7% of the time.

Note that power analyses must be conducted before data collection. It looks like you might have entered the details of the data you actually have here - what's called [post-hoc power calculation](http://daniellakens.blogspot.com/2014/12/observed-power-and-what-to-do-if-your.html). That would be a big mistake.

Comment: Thank you @Eoin. Originally, I have no intention to perform Power Analysis. I calculated the significant difference in the mean values of the two groups and found significant difference in the mean values. Then I was eventually asked to confirm if the small sample size in Group 2 would affect the significance. Can I conclude that the sample size of Group 2 does not affect its significant difference from Group 1? Or did I perform the correct analysis to confirm that sample size does not really make a difference in the significant difference of the mean values of the two groups?